# Gulp bundle is not running in Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, npm, gulp

I am trying to add a2 component to my angularjs project but when i tried running command gulp bundle it saya the following error

```
Unhandled rejection Error on fetch for  at file:///var/www/html/xper/
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
  at Error (native)
```

I have no idea of this error can anyone help me.

MY GULP TASK CODE:

```
gulp.task('bundle', function() {
   var SystemBuilder = require('systemjs-builder');
   var builder = new SystemBuilder();

builder.loadConfig('./system.config.js')
    .then(function(){
        var outputFile = 'dist/bundle.js';
        return builder.buildStatic('app', outputFile, {
           minify: true,
           mangle: true,
           rollup: true
        });console.log('hi')
    })
    .then(function(){
        console.log('bundle built successfully!');
    });
});
```

Comment: Please share the gulp task code

Comment: Randy,edited my code........

Comment: Could it be a typescript transpilation problem? It seems your code is simply missing a `catch` block. I'm not into TS that much though.